# How do I upload a png image in pygame as a sprite, without the black background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6, python-3.7

]How do I get my sprite to appear on the screen. i have been days at this and I couldn't get it to appear on the screen and it kept either taking over the screen as black.

import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Napoleon")

bg = pygame.image.load("apple.png").convert()
win.blit(bg, [0,0])

flower= pygame.image.load("flower2.png").convert()
win.blit(flower, [603,29])

pygame.display.update()

Comment: [pygame transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `convert()` try `convert_alpha()`.  Assuming your image has an alpha channel (PNG should be good) and it has been applied to  your background.  If your image has no alpha channel and you need a background gone, you should look into the `set_colorkey()` function.

Also, for future reference, you can format your code in your question by highlighting it all and pressing `CTRL+K`.  Makes it much easier to read (and you'll get faster answers!)